# Check that the "alpha" part of a string consists of only a certain sequence of characters - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

I am developing a listener to check if in a string representing a formula there are only `vg` digraphs such as "alpha" characters (a, b, c, etc ..). 

Eg:

`vg/1000 * 2` Correct!
`vl/1000 * 2` Wrong!

For now I have tried with regular expressions, using the following:
`(.*vg.*)+` but I have the impression that it is not the best solution.

I'm thinking about the best way to write this check in python.
Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.  "What is the best way?" is usually a wrapper around "give me code/design to solve this problem" -- which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Sorr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15HTd4Um1m4). Fixed....

Comment: I sitll don't understand the problem.  Your `re` is for the specific string `vg`, but your description implies that other letters are allowed.  However, if the solution works, is short, and you understand it, then you need to explain to us what a better solution could involve.

Comment: What I did is wrong because on the left and right of the diagram, match anything. It should only match the components of a formula (numbers and symbols)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a regular expression that only accepts `vg` as a sequence of letters, then:

```
'^(\d*([\.\,]\d+)?[-+/*]?(vg)?)*$'
```

Otherwise if you want to choose from a set of letter sequences:

```
'^(\d*([\.\,]\d+)?[-+/*]?(vg|otherSequence)?)*$'
```